# Want to display an Image if a customer group has a special price

Tags: magento-1.9, if, group-price

I want to display an image in corner of our product images if a customer is logged into a specific group and that group has a special price.

I have got the code for checking whether a customer is logged in and also check what group they are in. and I have got this to add a  if it is true. This is the code I have for this.

```
<?php       
        $_isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
        if($_isLoggedIn == true){
        $_myGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();          
        if($_myGroupId == 5){
        ?><div class="special"> </div><?php
                }
            }
    ?>
```

However, I need another IF statement to check if that product also has a special price for that customer group. I have done this before in the price.phtml using this code

```
<?php $login = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn(); //Check if User is Logged In
        if($login && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()==5)
        {
        $groupPrices = $_product->getData('group_price');
        $Groupprice= $groupPrices;
            if (is_null($groupPrices)) {
                $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('group_price');
                if ($attribute){
                    $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($_product);
                    $groupPrices = $_product->getData('group_price');}} 
            /* check group price exit nor not */
             if (!is_null($groupPrices) || is_array($groupPrices)) {
                foreach ($groupPrices as $groupPrice) {  
                if($groupPrice['cust_group'] == Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()){
                $Groupprice = $groupPrice['website_price'];   
                 $Groupprice=$groupPrice['cust_group'];
                break;}} }
             /* $Groupprice  is null mean group price is not  exit*/
             if(!is_null($Groupprice)){
           //group price exits ?>
           <span class="price-label"><?php echo "Your Special Price " ?></span><?php}?>
```

But this code doesn't work in the view.phtml. I have had a little play around and I can't seem to get it to work, Could someone help me adding another IF statement to my original IF statement.

If I am not being clear please let me know. and Thank you in advance.

Comment: Adam,is it products view page?

Comment: yea i have put the code in my view.phtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi You need change product object  to  $_product as product page then you did not load  afterLoad function

```
    <?php 
    $login = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn(); 
//Check if User is Logged In
            if($login)
            {
            $groupPrices = $_product->getData('group_price');
            $Groupprice= $groupPrices;
                /* check group price exit nor not */
                 if (!is_null($groupPrices) || is_array($groupPrices)) {
                    foreach ($groupPrices as $groupPrice) {
                    /* match with current customer group */
                    if($groupPrice['cust_group'] == Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()){
                    echo $Groupprice = $groupPrice['website_price'];
                    echo "<br/>";   
                    echo $Groupprice=$groupPrice['cust_group'];
                    break;
                    }
                    }

                 }
                 /* $Groupprice  is null mean group price is not  exit*/
                 if(!is_null($Groupprice)){
                     //group price eixts
                     ?>
                     <span class="price-label"><?php echo "Special Group Price " ?></span>
                    <?php 
                 }else{
                     //Group price is exits.
                     ?>
                     <span class="price-label"><?php echo "Now" ?></span> 
                 <?php }
            ?>
```

Comment: After a bit of tinkering it works perfect. Once again you save the day. Thank you :)