# customer group restriction and price management

Tags: magento-1.9, php

How can i set different prices for customer group also a retailer should be able to see only his price but the dealer should be able to see the dealer price as well as the retailer price.

Comment: is retailer  and dealer is a customer group?

Comment: yes, they are a customer group the idea is to show the dealer how much of a discount he is getting compared to other group members like retailer, partner etc

Comment: from which page are you doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is provide to show customer group wise price and It is magento feature.

You can customer group wise from admin.So goto admin`>Catalog>manage product>Select a product >Price tab >` here you can get customer group wise price

This Price will show when a customer is logged in magento site

If want to show group wise price then check this [Want to display an Image if a customer group has a special price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38334/want-to-display-an-image-if-a-customer-group-has-a-special-price/38342#38342)

**Edit:**

code is

```
$groupPrices = $_product->getData('group_price');

if (is_null($groupPrices)) {
    $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('group_price');
    if ($attribute) {
        $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($_product);
        $groupPrices = $_product->getData('group_price');
    }
}

if (is_null($groupPrices) || !is_array($groupPrices)) {
    return $_product->getPrice();
}


$matchedPrice = $_product->getPrice();
foreach ($groupPrices as $groupPrice) {
    if ($groupPrice['website_price'] < $matchedPrice) {
        $matchedPrice = $groupPrice['website_price'];
        echo  Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($matchedPrice, false);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know that but it only shows the price that is assigned to the group but what is needed is that the dealer should be able to see prices of other groups as well but normal groups will be able to see only their price according to the priorities of the group
thank you for your response

Comment: I have 5 groups 
registered user:- can see only his price
corporate user:- can see his and registered user price
dealer:- can see his , registered and corporate price
partner:- can see his, registered, dealer and corporate price
staff:- can see all the prices

Comment: check my code....